# ayuda con visualizar datos en app

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-cloud-firestore

tengo un problema, es sobre guardar datos y luego leerlos mediante el firestone, al momento de guardar lo hace bien , pero cuando quiero consultar lo que guarde la app se cierra, no se mucho sobre app

```
package com.example.luis.myapplication;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {

    private String name, brand, description;
    private double price;
    private int qty;

    public Product(String name, String brand, String description, double price, int qty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }
}
```

en el logcat entre tantos codigos me sale esto...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.example.luis.myapplication.Product does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped  

  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:524)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:680)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:674)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:503)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:242)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:97)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:203)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:121)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:183)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:101)
        at com.example.luis.myapplication.ProductsActivity$1.onSuccess(ProductsActivity.java:55)
        at com.example.luis.myapplication.ProductsActivity$1.onSuccess(ProductsActivity.java:43)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

entre tantos codigos me sale esto...

Comment: el error dice `Product does not define a no-argument constructor`, asi que solo deberias agregar `public Product(){}`

Comment: Ya lo probe... pero ahora me sale otro error.

Comment: agrega el nuevo error, no se te puede ayudar si no mencionas cuál es

Comment: me salia un error con referencia a los metodos, pero lo solucione poniendo: multiDexEnabled true. gracias!